# Controlling a balance wheel using a Unity script

Tags: unity, physics

I am working on a small demonstration project with Unity [like this](https://youtu.be/3MUL65-vZHY?t=78) (screenshot from footage below).

[image]

I don't want to use Unity physics, which is too heavy. I plan to create a rotation function with ratio params for gears.  But I am not sure how to control the balance wheel rotation like that video, I tried animation tools which is hard to make the acceleration like real physics.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's difficult for me to understand what you're trying to achieve. In the given video excerpt you're sharing there is no mentions of "balance wheel" only "escape wheel". Is that the movement you desire to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, now I know it should use SHM function. {\displaystyle x(t)=A\cos \left(\omega t-\varphi \right),}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it can be simulated by simple harmonic motion function.
[image: simple harmonic motion]

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained how you implemented this formula in your code to coordinate with the rest of the motion of the mechanism.